# How to create a translation and get author and post date copied from the original node

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

When creating translations of news I want them to have the same author and post date as the original node, so that I (or the translator) don't have to copy paste. Anyone know a module or snippet for this?

Comment: how are you doing the translation?

Comment: I'm now doing it by hand, translate tab - create translation etc.

Comment: Thank you for the very high quality answers to my very first question! I love this site.

Answer (score 2):

The **Synchronize translations** module, part of the **Internationalization (i18n) package**, allows you to synchronize fields and other node elements.

After enabling it, have a look at *admin/structure/types/manage/your-content-type*  options, in "synchronize translations", and check the boxes *author* and *post date*

[image: synchronize translations options]

Comment: Thanks. This is very easy to use. However, I have had unconsistent results with this earlier and apparently still have, as it's supposed to keep the sync even when editing fields, but it just doesn't do that. Either it's a bug or the documentation is wrong. Anyway I would prefer not to keep the sync forever, only copy the fields at creation of translation.

Comment: you're welcome. If you prefer not to keep the sync forever, of course it can't help. I don't know what you exactly mean by "unconsistent results ... supposed to keep the sync even when editing fields" ? Just as testimony, I've got this in use on a 3 languages website, with thousands of translated pages, and almost complex workflows where diff users edit the same content successively. And it keeps author and post date sync. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't know about the **Synchronize translations** module like me, you could do a form_alter() in a custom module that would prefill these, eg, something along these lines:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id) {

    case 'article_node_form': // or whatever node type you want this to happen with...

      if (arg(1) == 'add' && !empty($_GET['translation']) && !empty($_GET['target']) && ($source = node_load($_GET['translation'])) && i18n_node_type_enabled($source)) { // this logic pulled from i18n_node_i18n_context_language()
        $form['author']['name']['#default_value'] = $source->name; // just changed $node-> to $source-> in the #description so it matches the new default value
        $form['author']['date']['#description'] = t('Format: %time. The date format is YYYY-MM-DD and %timezone is the time zone offset from UTC. Leave blank to use the time of form submission.', array('%time' => !empty($source->date) ? date_format(date_create($source->date), 'Y-m-d H:i:s O') : format_date($source->created, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s O'), '%timezone' => !empty($source->date) ? date_format(date_create($source->date), 'O') : format_date($source->created, 'custom', 'O')));
        $form['author']['date']['#default_value'] = format_date($source->created, 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s O'); // CORRECTION (had $source->date... in here originally)
      }

      break;

    // any other $form_id's here

  }

}
```

but I've only done a quick test using admin to see if it works; I am sure permissions would come into play if you or your translators didn't have the right permissions to change the author and/or date.  Also, this only works I would imagine on the initial translation, eg, when the "add translation" link is in there and creates the url with the extra _GET variables.

Comment: Thanks. Brilliant work. I will try this. Operating on the initial translation was my preferation.